# File disappeared after mv command

Tags: unix, mv

I lost few files while trying to run mv in unix script.

Command in script

```
user:/opt/app/intech_collected1/ccp > head failed.sh
#!/bin/bash
mv in4_G_004_0086147809_20160503_008.s /opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/
mv in4_G_001_0005027604_20160504_001.s /opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/
mv in4_G_008_0008299443_20160504_007.s /opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/
mv in4_G_008_0008301379_20160504_007.s /opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/
mv R_0_3_10-1_0_1_0_0_160504033902_008.s /opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/
mv in4_G_002_0001115247_20160504_002.s /opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/
mv in4_G_001_0086147949_20160504_008.s /opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/
mv in4_G_008_0086145465_20160503_008.s /opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/
mv in4_G_002_0086095468_20160503_008.s /opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/
```

I did `bash -x <filename>`

while running, the command appeared like below

```
+ mv in4_G_001_0008315698_20160505_007.s $'/opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/\r'
+ mv in4_G_001_0086037914_20160504_008.s $'/opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/\r'
+ mv in4_G_008_0008299994_20160504_007.s $'/opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/\r'
+ mv in4_G_008_0086161387_20160504_008.s $'/opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/\r'
+ mv in4_G_002_0001115198_20160504_002.s $'/opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/\r'
+ mv in4_G_008_0086161432_20160504_008.s $'/opt/app/intech_directory/intech_polled/ccp/\r'
```

Please see `\r` in the end.

Now I do not find the files in source or destination path.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

All those files except the last are irretrievably lost. They are written to a file named `\r`, or the line feed character. Only the last file to be `mv`-ed can still be found. You can give it a more readable name by doing `mv $'\r' more_readable_name`.

The reason is because the script `failed.sh` apparently has been stored with the Windows conventions of text files. Under Unix, a new line is literally the `\n` character. Under Windows, it is two characters: `\r\n`. This means that you did not write to the intended directory, but to the file `\r` in the directory.

For the future, configure your editor to adhere to the UNIX line endings, and/or run the utility `dos2unix` on the file.